# Page does not load when using the .then function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been working on a project and it requires me to use the .then function after creating schemas in the database but for some reason, every time I try to run the `res.render` function in the .then()function, the page does not load. It tells me my app is running on the port, and I am connected to my database, and everything seems to be fine. I am using cloud9, and here is my code for the index.js file

```
function getVenues (bars){
        bars.map((eachBar) => {
            Venue.findOne({
                id: eachBar.id,
                title: eachBar.name,
                image: eachBar.image_url,
                url: eachBar.url,
                rating: eachBar.rating
            }, (err, venue) => {
                if(err) return (err);
                if(!venue){
                    var newVenue = new Venue({
                        id: eachBar.id,
                        title: eachBar.name,
                        image: eachBar.image_url,
                        rating: eachBar.rating,
                        url: eachBar.url
                    }).save((err, venue) => {
                        if(err) return err;
                    })
                }
            })
        })
}


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
request.get('http://ipinfo.io/' + req.headers['x-forwarded-for'], {json: true}, function (e, r){
    client.search({
        term: "bars",
        latitude:r.body.loc.split(",")[0],
        longitude: r.body.loc.split(",")[1]
    }).then(response => {
        getVenues(response.jsonBody.businesses).then(function(results){
                res.render('home', {
                    bars: results,
                    term: 'Bars near you',
                    authenticated: req.isAuthenticated()
                });
                console.log(results);
            });
        console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    });
});
});
```

Everything is defined and it shows no errors in my code. The problem here is that if I put the `res.render` function outside of the .then function, it works perfectly fine and everything loads, but right now, it just keeps on loading and gives be an error of `Error 502 - Bad Gateway` in the cloud9 site. Does anyone know why it happens and how to solve it?

Comment: you should add a .catch to trigger when there is an error accessing your api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your function `getVenues` doesn't return a `Promise` which would define `then` and `catch`. To get an array of venues as the result, you need to combine the results of each `Venue.findOne` call. This can be done by using `Promise.all` on the array of 'inner' Promises:

```
return Promise.all(bars.map(bar => {
    return Venue.findOne({...})
}))
```

This assumes that `Venue.findOne` returns value (or again a `Promise`). This is easy, if `findOne` already returns a `Promise` (should work like above) but works as follows if it only uses callbacks:

```
Venue.findOne({...}, (err, venue) => {
    if (err) return (err)
    if (venue) return venue
    return new Promise((fulfil, reject) => {
        let newVenue = new Venue({...})
            .save((err, venue) => {
                 if (err) reject(err)
                 else fulfil(venue)
            })
    })
```

Promises might return errors. For each promise you use, you should add a `catch`. Just add a `catch` right after the closing bracket of each `then` (or the last `then` if - in general - you have a cascade of thens) and you should see which error occurs:

```
client.search(...)
    .then(...)
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @Joachim Schirrmacher, turns out the function .then is not defined. Do you know any alternatives I can use for the .then part?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that first. The second of the `then` calls is on the return value of your `getVanues` function - which doesn't return a `Promise`, which would define a `then` function. You need to return one, composed of the results of the `findOne` results. I'll change the code in my answer.

Comment: I got it now! I added ```return new Promise``` at the beginning of my function and now it works! Thanks a bunch!